# Redundant code in hard fault handling of ARM Cortex-M processor

Tags: c, arm, interrupt, fault

From [FreeRTOS.org](https://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html), 
regarding *Debugging Hard Fault & Other Exceptions 
on ARM Cortex-M3 and ARM Cortex-M4 microcontrollers*, according to FreeRTOS guys we can use the following code in order to debug a ARM Cortex-M Hard Fault-

```
/* The fault handler implementation calls a function called
prvGetRegistersFromStack(). */
static void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
    __asm volatile
    (
        " tst lr, #4                                                \n"
        " ite eq                                                    \n"
        " mrseq r0, msp                                             \n"
        " mrsne r0, psp                                             \n"
        " ldr r1, [r0, #24]    <======== NOTE THIS LINE             \n"
        " ldr r2, handler2_address_const                            \n"
        " bx r2                                                     \n"
        " handler2_address_const: .word prvGetRegistersFromStack    \n"
    );
}
```

Now, to my understanding, the marked line has no effect and is not used in the counterpart `prvGetRegistersFromStack` function:

```
void prvGetRegistersFromStack( uint32_t *pulFaultStackAddress )
{
/* These are volatile to try and prevent the compiler/linker optimising them
away as the variables never actually get used.  If the debugger won't show the
values of the variables, make them global my moving their declaration outside
of this function. */
volatile uint32_t r0;
volatile uint32_t r1;
volatile uint32_t r2;
volatile uint32_t r3;
volatile uint32_t r12;
volatile uint32_t lr; /* Link register. */
volatile uint32_t pc; /* Program counter. */
volatile uint32_t psr;/* Program status register. */

    r0 = pulFaultStackAddress[ 0 ];
    r1 = pulFaultStackAddress[ 1 ];
    r2 = pulFaultStackAddress[ 2 ];
    r3 = pulFaultStackAddress[ 3 ];

    r12 = pulFaultStackAddress[ 4 ];
    lr = pulFaultStackAddress[ 5 ];
    pc = pulFaultStackAddress[ 6 ];
    psr = pulFaultStackAddress[ 7 ];

    /* When the following line is hit, the variables contain the register values. */
    for( ;; );
}
```

`pulFaultStackAddress` is passed using register `r0` by `mrseq r0, msp` or by `mrsne r0, psp` and it's the only argument used in the function. So is there a purpose for the `ldr r1, [r0, #24]` line ?

Comment: Why would you think it has no effect? At first glance, it appears to be part of the C calling convention on that compiler/architecture. I would disassemble the `prvGetRegistersFromStack` function and take a look at what is actually going on under the hood. It may actually be the case that r1 is not needed for that particular function, but is reserved for a particular use in some function calls. Consult your C compiler manuals/source code for an explicit explanation.

Comment: @jwdonahue `It may actually be the case that r1 is not needed for that particular function, but is reserved for a particular use in some function calls` if it's not needed for this particular function than why would they conclude that in this example? functions `HardFault_Handler ` and `prvGetRegistersFromStack ` are apart of the same example showing hard fault handling in arm cortex m, this is not a generic example but a specific one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPU, OS and compiler makers often collude to produce a standard [ABI (aka Abstract Binary Interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) for a particular platform. It's what allows you to link object files produced by different compilers/languages with your program. The calling conventions define how return values and parameters are passed between caller and called code, and other details required to allow inter-operable components written in different languages or compiled by different tools.

What you are seeing in the assembler code is an ABI detail that [should be documented by the ARM consortium](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html). In order to successfully call into C code from assembler, you must understand the ABI. Note that compiler writers are free to implement their calling conventions any way they wish, so your mileage may vary. That's why I suggested you check your C compiler documentation. Most C compilers provide configurable calling schemes, sometimes the platform ABI is the default, sometimes it's not.

Given that your target is an RTOS, it's possible they have their own ABI, in which case they probably modified an OSS compiler tool chain, but it is most likely that they follow the ARM Cortex ABI. In cases where the target board doesn't have any OS's available, all bets are off and you should consult the board maker for relevant documentation (if any).

Answer (score 0):

We might be reading too much into this.  I think it's just a kludge to push the prvGetRegistersFromStack address on to a 4 byte boundary (required by my M7 and external SDRAM).  They could use the align directive to achieve the same thing.

```
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
    __asm volatile
        (
            " tst lr, #4                                                \n"
            " ite eq                                                    \n"
            " mrseq r0, msp                                             \n"
            " mrsne r0, psp                                             \n"
            " ldr r2, handler2_address_const                            \n"
            " bx r2                                                     \n"
            " .align 4                                                  \n"
            " handler2_address_const: .word prvGetRegistersFromStack    \n"
        );
}
```

But hey, if it works who's to say which way's better :)

Cheers,
David

Comment: It is accessing the stack, maybe to prime the cache.  The accepted answer doesn’t make sense to me though;  I see why you added in.

Comment: Maybe, but again, why?  If anything you would want to invalidate the cache instead of priming it.

Comment: That is true.  I looked briefly at the code and it could be copy paste from another exception handler.

Comment: (cont) The [r0 + 24] is fetching what the PC was when the Hard Fault occurred. They might be previewing it in the debugger before jumping to the prvGetRegistersFromStack function.
If I remove that line, then the code doesn't work.  r2 gets loaded with the wrong address for prvGetRegistersFromStack (offset by 2 bytes).  That might be because I'm using external SDRAM, but it is still good practice to align addresses on 4 byte boundaries.