# Storage layout of C objects

Tags: c, language-lawyer, function-parameter, memory-layout

The storage layout of C objects is mostly not defined. As far as I know only for `struct` members and array elements, the layout is defined.

Interestingly for function parameters the C11 standard explicitly mentions that the layout is not defined:

> The layout of the storage for parameters is unspecified. (C11 § 6.9.1 P 9)

I was wondering if the standard also explicitly defines that for other objects, e.g., objects with automatic storage duration, the layout is undefined. Is someone aware of this? I couldn't find anything about this in the standard.

What about objects with internal or external linkage?

Comment: You are mixing up the storage of the different storage classes and the storage layout of different types. The former is not defined for any, only the lifetime is defined.

Comment: What's more interesting, that statement seems to be the only instance of the word "layout" in the standard, so I'm not even sure what it's talking about here.

Comment: Many architectures have ABIs where first function parameters are passed in registers. However, one is still allowed to take the address of a function parameter. To avoid unnecessary overhead, compilers can do all sorts of optimizations, like copying the registers to stack in some random order (possibly even differing from one invocation to the next). I do believe the purpose of [C11 6.9.1p9](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1) is to explicitly state that sort of approach is expected and allowed; that the addresses of the function parameters are essentially unpredictable.

Comment: See my [recent answer, regarding ABI's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088152/redundant-code-in-hard-fault-handling-of-arm-cortex-m-processor/51110090#51110090), to a related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think that there is an explicit mention of the fact that we can't know anything about relative object layout. In fact, the C standard is even more radical than that, you are not even allowed to do comparison with the `<` operator on two variables that are not elements of the same array, nor may you do arithmetic between pointers to objects that are not part of the same array.

So the whole question of "layout" cannot even be formulate with the terminology that the C standard provides.

Comment: ITYM " not even allowed to do comparison with the `<` operator on two pointers that do not point into the same array"?

Comment: @SteveSummit: The Standard expressly indicates that it is possible to convert an object's address to a character pointer and use that to access the bytes therein.  Because the Standard's sloppy and inconsistent usage of the term "object", it can't describe the pointer as identifying a character-array object (if the character-array object is created when the parent object is created, any access to non-character parts of the the object would also access the character-array object using a non-character type, thus invoking ub by 6.5p7, but the Standard fails to offer...

Comment: ...any other description of the object's lifetime).  I don't think the authors of the Standard worried about such things because they expected that compiler writers would recognize how quality implementations should behave in what should be obvious cases, regardless of whether the Standard mandated such behavior.